# Adding a Banner/Message to all Pages on Web Server

Tags: windows, apache, webserver

I have two web servers, Windows machines running Apache.

One is a backup of the other, so if one fails the other can be used instead.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Apache so it displays a small banner/message on each page it serves to say that the user is running on the backup server?

I did find a 3rd party module (mod-substitute-append http://code.google.com/p/mod-substitute-append/) that *may* have done what I wanted, but there appears to be no documentation for it, and when downloaded looks like it was written to be installed on a Linux machine.

Does anyone have any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache 2.2 ships with mod_substitute: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html

Apache 2.4 ships with mod_sed: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html

From the documentation, mod_sed does similar things to mod_substitute_append (which I have used, on Linux). It might be worth grabbing an Apache 2.4 Windows binary and seeing how you get on.

Comment: That's great, mod_substitute in 2.2 did the trick. Thank you.